# Pester & AzureAdPreview Module

Tags: powershell, pester

My system-tests that validate some basis group setup fail when I invoke all tests (*.tests.ps1) via `Invoke-Pester`.

The error is `The term 'Get-AzureADObjectSetting' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file`. This cmdlet is provided via module `AzureAdPreview`.

When I run the same test-file with `Invoke-Pester -Script ./GroupFoobar.tests.ps1` is this error not raised.

Loads Pester modules different in some situations - I am using Pester version 4.0.4?

Comment: It's hard to say what is occurring without seeing your code. One possible explanation could be that the module is getting unloaded by one of your other test scripts.

Comment: Hmm but when when I ensure that the "problematic" test file is first loaded by "Invoke-Pester" occurrences the error...

Comment: Perhaps it’s the reverse then, another one of your scripts is calling import-module.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, using the `-Force` switch for the `AzureAdPreview` solved my problem:

`Import-Module Pester
Import-Module AzureAdPreview -Force
Import-Module Microsoft.Xrm.Data.Powershell
...`